# Window will not display using code from "Cocoa Programming For OS X", 5 Ed., Ex. 1

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa, nswindow

I am starting to work through the book "Cocoa Programming For OS X", 5 Ed.

I am running macOS 10.12 and Xcode 8 Version 8.0 (8A218a).

I am building the first exercise and running it as on p. 17. The code builds and runs, but no window will display. I have diffed my code with the solution code, and there are not differences, so I think the problem is in how my project is set up? If you are comfortable downloading and looking at my project, it is here:

https://www.dropbox.com/s/7adsrn0zqg2s7vx/Ch1_RandomPassword.zip?dl=0

If I build and run the solution code, the app runs as expected. Can anyone suggest how I might troubleshoot this further?

Comment: `applicationDidFinishLaunching`'s parameter `aNotification: NSNotification` is missing.

Comment: @willeke, thanks so much! The code was not building with the variables that were automatically in the code, and I removed them without knowing what they are responsible for...onward.... :)

Comment: How can I accept your answer? There is no checkmark next to your message...?